# [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom:]

Tags: maven, scala-gatling

I am trying to integrate maven with Gatling and I am getting below error message. This is my first time of doing this and I really need help.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repsoitory with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/gatling/highcharts/gatling-highcharts-maven-archetype/2.2.1/gatling-highcharts-maven-archetype-2.2.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.203 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-04T11:18:56-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-highcharts-maven-archetype:2.2.1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue. It gets resolved when I replace `mvn archetype:generate` with `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate` as stated by Robert in [this github issue comment](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype/issues/76#issuecomment-282680691).

Answer (score 3):

I just found it in Maven's own website. They have given it as follows:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B 
        -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes 
        -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
        -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 
        -DgroupId=com.company 
        -DartifactId=project 
        -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT 
        -Dpackage=com.company.project
```

As we can see the `archeTypeVersion` is also mentioned. It worked for me. So will work for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

you need to aad plugin into your `pom.xml`, you can find plugin below:

```
<!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

for more you can refer from https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/plugin-info.html

and if you already added this plugin into your `pom.xml` then you can try to delete `.m2` repository folder and update your maven project and rebuild project and run it.